# JavaFX and Swing colour mismatch

Tags: java, swing, javafx, colors

We are implementing a JavaFX ColorPicker for our swing based GUI. We noticed that the opacity of the colours seem to cause them to look different when shown on a panel.

We've set up a small working example to demonstrate the issue. If you uncomment the two lines the colours look identical. Once you start using non-opaque colours there's a discrepancy. The left panel is the Swing colour and the right is the JavaFX colour:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ColourMismatch
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double opacity = 0.5;
        float alpha = 0.5f;

//      opacity = 1.0;
//      alpha = 1.0f;

        javafx.scene.paint.Color jfxColour = new javafx.scene.paint.Color(0.302, 0.83, 0.1, opacity);
        java.awt.Color swingColour = new java.awt.Color(0.302f, 0.83f, 0.1f, alpha);

        JDialog dlg = new JDialog();
        dlg.getContentPane().setBackground(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
        dlg.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel swingPanel = new JPanel();
        swingPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        swingPanel.setBackground(swingColour);
        dlg.getContentPane().add(swingPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        jfxPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        dlg.getContentPane().add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), jfxColour);
                jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
            }
        });

        dlg.setModal(true);
        dlg.setSize(416, 600);
        dlg.setVisible(true);
        dlg.dispose();

        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

Any idea how to compensate for this or why our code is causing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **containers** (Swing vs. JavaFX) have different background colors, so the color which shines through your transparent component is different. I slightly modified your `run()` method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
   Pane contents = new Pane();
   contents.setBackground(new Background(
              new BackgroundFill(jfxColour, new CornerRadii(0), new Insets(0))));

   Scene scene = new Scene(contents);

   jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
}
```

This still reproduces the issue.

However, if I now set the `Scene` background color to `BLACK`, the colors are rendered the same:

```
@Override
public void run() {
   Pane contents = new Pane();
   contents.setBackground(new Background(
              new BackgroundFill(jfxColour, new CornerRadii(0), new Insets(0))));

   // Scene scene = new Scene(contents);
   Scene scene = new Scene(contents, javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);
                                                         // !!!!!!!!
   jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
}
```

In summary, if you do

```
dlg.getContentPane().setBackground(SomeAwtColor);
```

you also need to do

```
Scene scene = new Scene(contents, CorrespondingJFXColor);
```

and then add your transparent components to the `Scene`.